# CocoaPod : [!] Unable to find a specification for `PODEMO`

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have created my own sample PODEMO for learning. It's live and showing on cocoa-pod website.
But when i am installing it in other project, It showing me error like below. Please help here..

[!] Unable to find a specification for `PODEMO`
You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After using below commands in terminal, it's working fine.

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

And then :

```
$ pod setup
```

I'd also recommend running :

```
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
```